# Visual C# Random Number File Writer

Tags: c#

```
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declare int variable.
        int randomNumber = 0;

        // Declare a StreamWriter variable.
        StreamWriter outputFile;

        // Get the number of random integers to hold in file.
        int number = int.Parse(txt_Number.Text);

        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Create the selected file.
            outputFile = File.CreateText(saveFile.FileName);

            // Create a Random Object.
            Random Rand = new Random();

            for (int count = 0; count < number; count++)
            {
                // Get random integers and assign them to randomNumber.
                randomNumber = Rand.Next(1, 101);

                // Write data to the file.
                outputFile.WriteLine(randomNumber);

                // Close the file.
                outputFile.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("File saved in path:" + saveFile.FileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Display an error message.
            MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
        }
    }

    private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the TextBox.
        txt_Number.Text = ""; 
    }

    private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the form.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

The question is: Create a program that writes a series of random numbers to a file. Each random number should be in the range of 1 through 100. The application should let the user specify how many random numbers the file will hold.

The code is working but i' having problems with the output writeline.
Each time i'm running the program, it says exception unhandled and cannot write to a Closed TextWriter.
Also instead of saving multiple random numbers, it is saving only one.
Any help concerning these 2 problems would be great.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? Your code tries to write to the file after closing it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in front of the loop where you write to the file. Run your program and step through the code line by line with the F10 key. Pay close attention -- very, very close, focused attention -- to each and every thing you see your code doing. You will be enlightened. I can't promise cosmic consciousness, but you'll at least get your code working.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: hey, I use this approach on other problems, too. Do you think this is a generic approach on solving problems?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Let's not go crazy here.

Answer (score -2):

Your error is in the for loop here:

```
for (int count = 0; count < number; count++)
        {
            // Get random integers and assign them to randomNumber.
            randomNumber = Rand.Next(1, 101);

            // Write data to the file.
            outputFile.WriteLine(randomNumber);

            // Close the file.
            outputFile.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("File saved in path:" + saveFile.FileName);
        }
```

You close the file before iterating through all the numbers. Thus, you cannot write past the first number. The close function should be outside the for loop like so:

```
for (int count = 0; count < number; count++)
        {
            // Get random integers and assign them to randomNumber.
            randomNumber = Rand.Next(1, 101);

            // Write data to the file.
            outputFile.WriteLine(randomNumber);

            MessageBox.Show("File saved in path:" + saveFile.FileName);
        }


        // Close the file outside for loop
        outputFile.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually did not realise this mistake at first

Comment: You should not recommend using `Close` directly. You should be recommending the `using` statements which will call `Close` and `Dispose` correctly